# How to enhance a class in Codename One API

Tags: codenameone

I'm looking to add functionality to the built in Java SDK classes beyond the CLDC 1.1 standard which is where the API seems to be compatible with. Specifically looking to implement StringBuffer#replace(...)

What is the best way to go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

cldc1.1 is a very old standard. Codename One supports far more than what that standard had but retained the filename due to legacy issues.

There is a guide on how to use the Codename One source and contribute it back to the git repository: http://codenameone.com/blog/how-to-use-the-codename-one-sources.html

However, the main issue is the need to fix this for all OS's which is pretty challenging.

To just fix the stubs for the method to appear to compile you can change the project [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/tree/master/Ports/CLDC11). However, this will only work for targets where the method is already there (Android, JavaSE etc.).

You will then need to make sure there is an implementation for all other targets:

For Windows you will need to fix the ikvm target and fork, for iOS you will need to fix the code in the [JavaAPI directory](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/tree/master/vm/JavaAPI) under the VM directory for JavaScript you will need to contribute your changes to [TeaVM](http://teavm.org/) if required.

For older platforms you will need to implement your changes into the [retroweaver support](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/tree/master/Ports/retro) although this might not be as relevant.

Comment: Shai, thanks for the speedy reply. It took me a while to figure out that in the emulator the JDK implementation is used. I gather that the only way for me to test the different port implementations is to send a project to the builder servers? Additionally, where are unit-tests stored?

Comment: The build servers won't work since changes you make locally to the VM implementations will not be reflected there. Changing the VM is **really** hard even for us which is why we try to add external functionality in the com.codename1 packages instead. Our unit tests aren't public as they are pretty rough. We need to have something closer to a proper TCK but never had the resources to build up something like that.

Comment: It is quite unfortunately that effectively it's not possible for an outsider to improve on that part of the code. Supporting more of the API makes it much easier to share common code between client and server without creating polyfill's all over the place.

Comment: It's totally possible to enhance that part of the code, it's just difficult as I explained above. It's difficult for us too which is why we are always hesitant and slow to update things in the VM API. Changes to Codename One proper are portable but VM code needs to be repeated for every single platform...